# NAudio - converting AAC audio to mp3 or wav

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio, aac

Given an aac audio byte array, convert to an mp3 audio in bytes. This is what I tried, but I this an exception

> "Got a frame at sample rate 24000, in an MP3 with sample rate 16000.
>   Mp3FileReader does not support sample rate changes"

```
  public static byte[] AacToMp3(byte[] aacAudioBytes)
    {
        using (var aacStream = new MemoryStream(aacAudioBytes))
        using (var mp3stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var reader = new Mp3FileReader(aacStream))// or I tried AudioFileReader/MediaFoundationReader
        using (var mp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(mp3stream, reader.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.ABR_32))
        {
            reader.CopyTo(mp3Writer);
            return mp3stream.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Same problem here. I'll post an answer when I find one.